# Manipulating dataset to account for repeated measures

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr, tidyr

Given:

```
df <- data.frame(
                  CompanyID=c("Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers"
                            ,"Drinkers","Drinkers", "Liquders","Liquders","Liquders","PelletCoffeeCo","PelletCoffeeCo"),
                  Email= c("john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com","john@coffee.com","john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com", 
                          "john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com",
                          "george@liquid.com","george@liquid.com","george@liquid.com","stacy@pelletcoffee.com",
                        "stacy@pelletcoffee.com"),
                  Day= c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","1","2","3","1","2"),
                 var1= c(4,5,5,5,2,3,2,7,6,5,7,6,6,2,3))
```

I need to figure out how to get to:

```
df2 <- data.frame(CompanyID=c("Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers","Drinkers"
                            ,"Drinkers","Drinkers", "Liquders","Liquders","Liquders","Liquders","Liquders","Liquders",
                            "Liquders","Liquders","Liquders","Liquders", "PelletCoffeeCo","PelletCoffeeCo","PelletCoffeeCo",
                            "PelletCoffeeCo","PelletCoffeeCo","PelletCoffeeCo","PelletCoffeeCo","PelletCoffeeCo",
                            "PelletCoffeeCo","PelletCoffeeCo"),
                  Email= c("john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com","john@coffee.com","john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com", 
                             "john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com", "john@coffee.com",
                           "george@liquid.com","george@liquid.com","george@liquid.com","george@liquid.com","george@liquid.com",
                           "george@liquid.com","george@liquid.com","george@liquid.com","george@liquid.com","george@liquid.com","stacy@pelletcoffee.com",
                           "stacy@pelletcoffee.com","stacy@pelletcoffee.com","stacy@pelletcoffee.com","stacy@pelletcoffee.com",
                           "stacy@pelletcoffee.com","stacy@pelletcoffee.com","stacy@pelletcoffee.com","stacy@pelletcoffee.com",
                           "stacy@pelletcoffee.com"),
                  Day= c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",
                         "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"),
                  var1= c(4,5,5,5,2,3,2,7,6,5,7,6,6, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

Explanation:
I have data where I surveyed people once a day over a course of 10 days. In a perfect world, I would have 10 responses from each participant, denoted by day1:day10. However, due to non-response, some participants gave 3 responses, others, 6, and others 10 and etc. I'm setting the data up to run a growth model, and so I need the column "Day" to always read Day1 - Day 10, regardless if there's data for those responses. I've tried to demonstrate this by adding NA's to rows that don't have all 10 days of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  complete(nesting(CompanyID,Email), Day = seq(min(Day), max(Day), 1L)) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Output:

```
        CompanyID                  Email Day var1
1        Drinkers        john@coffee.com   1    4
2        Drinkers        john@coffee.com   2    5
3        Drinkers        john@coffee.com   3    5
4        Drinkers        john@coffee.com   4    5
5        Drinkers        john@coffee.com   5    5
6        Drinkers        john@coffee.com   6    2
7        Drinkers        john@coffee.com   7    3
8        Drinkers        john@coffee.com   8    2
9        Drinkers        john@coffee.com   9    7
10       Drinkers        john@coffee.com  10    6
11       Liquders      george@liquid.com   1    7
12       Liquders      george@liquid.com   2   NA
13       Liquders      george@liquid.com   3    6
14       Liquders      george@liquid.com   4    6
15       Liquders      george@liquid.com   5   NA
16       Liquders      george@liquid.com   6   NA
17       Liquders      george@liquid.com   7   NA
18       Liquders      george@liquid.com   8   NA
19       Liquders      george@liquid.com   9   NA
20       Liquders      george@liquid.com  10   NA
21 PelletCoffeeCo stacy@pelletcoffee.com   1    2
22 PelletCoffeeCo stacy@pelletcoffee.com   2   NA
23 PelletCoffeeCo stacy@pelletcoffee.com   3    3
24 PelletCoffeeCo stacy@pelletcoffee.com   4   NA
25 PelletCoffeeCo stacy@pelletcoffee.com   5   NA
26 PelletCoffeeCo stacy@pelletcoffee.com   6   NA
27 PelletCoffeeCo stacy@pelletcoffee.com   7   NA
28 PelletCoffeeCo stacy@pelletcoffee.com   8   NA
29 PelletCoffeeCo stacy@pelletcoffee.com   9   NA
30 PelletCoffeeCo stacy@pelletcoffee.com  10   NA
```

**Edit:**

The code above fills each group's Day column values with a complete set of Day values defined by the minimum and maximum of the existing values in that column (i.e. 1 and 10, respectively). The groups by which these Day values are filled can be redefined as needed, but I chose to define them here as Company + Email with the line "nesting(CompanyID,Email)". The data.frame() line is just there to convert the output to a data.frame instead of a tibble. If a data.frame output isn't necessary, feel free to replace or remove that line.

Comment: Awesome! Thank so much. It worked like a charm.

I have a number of other variables, x1:x10, I'm hoping it'll work the same. 
Could you explain the functions? I see how it works, but not sure how complete and nesting works together-- and then why the need to add the data.frame argument at the end?

Comment: @D500 - No problem. See the explanation added above.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a data frame of the unique company ID.
Next, create a data frame of the desired days.

Cross Join these together.

Then join to your original dataset to fill out the table.

```
comp <- data.frame(CompanyID = unique(df$CompanyID))
Day <- data.frame(Day = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"))

compDay <- merge(comp, Day, all = TRUE)

dfday <- merge(df, compDay, by = c("CompanyID", "Day"), all = TRUE)
```